# get all values using get paremeters in java

Tags: java, javascript, apache-flex, flex3

I'm passing the some values url from flex to java example:
URL format:

```
../mahesh/initUser.do?method=fwdAccDetails&securityId=mUuB3/p/ky5JhZPY5T8Znf01YCcIarIalQiGEXPMMsOkWDX+KtT4fx2gMML+uup8
```

After I'm tiring to get `"securityId"` values in java like

`request.getParameter("securityId")`

But I'm getting following values only

**mUuB3/p/ky5JhZPY5T8Znf01YCcIarIalQiGEXPMMsOkWDX KtT4fx2gMML uup8**

- symbol getting empty space in java side..

Here is my Flex code:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('../mahesh/initUser.do?method=fwdAccDetails&securityId='+value+'),'_s‌​elf');
```

I didn't get full values.. any one can help me how I will get correct values in Java..

Comment: when an URL gets decoded, `+` signs are replaced by a space. Can't you use another character? You could also re-encode the output.

Comment: @TimS. Thanx for your reply. sorry..i dont know how to encode in client side then decode in server side.. Can you please explain u have time..do u have any example

Comment: @Engineer: i'm newly for flex.. can you give any example.. i'm using following url passing  navigateToURL(new URLRequest('../mahesh/initUser.do?method=fwdAccDetails&securityId='+value+'),'_self');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just resolve my issue for following code in a javURLDecoder.decode(param1AfterEncoding.replace("+", "%2B"), "UTF-8").replace("%2B", "+") 
Now its working fine only.. i dint other special character will work fine.. i will check it later..

Answer (score 1):

You should use the encodeURIComponent()-Function to properly encode your securityId.

```
value = encodeURIComponent(value);
navigateToURL(new URLRequest('../mahesh/initUser.do?method=fwdAccDetails&securityId='+value+'),'_s‌​elf');
```

That way your String will be correct on the Java side.

If you want to read more about proper escaping, have a look at [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) (Same arguments apply for Flex and JavaScript).

Comment: :i'm passing following values from flex L3CKYDr49ppJR4kZlDvM+tR2ElxAtpa/yro4ozB/6odCuKD7AcyjWzveOoj/2lJZ                                             After i'm getting the values in java                             URLCodec encoder = new URLCodec();
String result = encoder.encode(request.getParameter("id"));
System.out.println("resultd--"+id);                                   Finally its printing  following values L3CKYDr49ppJR4kZlDvM+tR2ElxAtpa%2Fyro4ozB%2F6odCuKD7AcyjWzveOoj%2F2lJZnow slash symbol not displaying can you help me..?